# Pure virtual inheritance, multiple inheritance, and C4505

Tags: c++, destructor, multiple-inheritance, pure-virtual

So I have an abstract base class with no abstract methods.  In order to enforce abstractness, I've declared the (non-trivial) destructor as pure virtual:

```
class AbstractClass
{
public:
  AbstractClass()
  {
    std::wcout << L"AbstractClass::AbstractClass()" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~AbstractClass() = 0
  {
    std::wcout << L"AbstractClass::~AbstractClass()" << std::endl;
  }
};

class ConcreteClass : public AbstractClass
{
public:
  ConcreteClass()
  {
    std::wcout << L"ConcreteClass::ConcreteClass()" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~ConcreteClass()
  {
    std::wcout << L"ConcreteClass::~ConcreteClass()" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

This builds and works as expected; the output for a code block that simply defines an instance of ConcreteClass is

```
    AbstractClass::AbstractClass()
    ConcreteClass::ConcreteClass()
    ConcreteClass::~ConcreteClass()
    AbstractClass::~AbstractClass()
```

Now, when I have derive AbstractClass from another class used as an interface class, itself having a (trivial) virtual destructor (pure or otherwise), it still works:

```
class IAlpha
{
public:
  virtual ~IAlpha() = 0 {}
};

class AbstractClass : public IAlpha
{
public:
  AbstractClass()
  {
    std::wcout << L"AbstractClass::AbstractClass()" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~AbstractClass() = 0
  {
    std::wcout << L"AbstractClass::~AbstractClass()" << std::endl;
  }
};

class ConcreteClass : public AbstractClass
{
public:
  ConcreteClass()
  {
    std::wcout << L"ConcreteClass::ConcreteClass()" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~ConcreteClass()
  {
    std::wcout << L"ConcreteClass::~ConcreteClass()" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

The problem arises when I attempt to implement two different interfaces in this manner:

```
class IAlpha
{
public:
  virtual ~IAlpha() = 0 {}
};

class IBeta
{
public:
  virtual ~IBeta() = 0 {}
};

class AbstractClass : public IAlpha, public IBeta
{
public:
  AbstractClass()
  {
    std::wcout << L"AbstractClass::AbstractClass()" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~AbstractClass() = 0
  {
    std::wcout << L"AbstractClass::~AbstractClass()" << std::endl;
  }
};

class ConcreteClass : public AbstractClass
{
public:
  ConcreteClass()
  {
    std::wcout << L"ConcreteClass::ConcreteClass()" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual ~ConcreteClass()
  {
    std::wcout << L"ConcreteClass::~ConcreteClass()" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

At this point, when building, I receive the following warning:

```
warning C4505: 'AbstractClass::~AbstractClass' :
unreferenced local function has been removed
```

Strangely enough, however, the output still shows `AbstractClass::~AbstractClass()` getting called.

Is this a bug in MSVC9 (VS 2008)?  Can I safely ignore this warning?

Edit:  I've tried separating the pure virtual method definitions from the class definition as well, as apparently the `= 0 {}` syntax is not actually valid.  Unfortunately, C4505 still shows up, whether I specify `inline` or not.

Since I've found no way to `#pragma` out this warning just for these methods (the warning gets triggered from other parts of the code), I may have to remove the pure virtual specifier from `AbstractClass` and rely on making the constructors protected.  Not an ideal solution, but it beats rearchitecting the class hierarchy to get around an erroneous warning.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in MSVC++ 2010 and earlier. The code actually gets
called even though the compiler claims to have removed the code. It seems to be
fixed in MSVC++ 2012. Other compilers like gcc or clang do not emit a warning.
The syntax "... = 0 {...}" is illegal according to the C++03 standard section 10.4.2 (even though MSVC++ does not complain) as it has already been pointed out:

> Note: a function declaration cannot provide both a pure-specifier and
>   a definition

However, defining a pure virtual destructor in general is not illegal and section 12.4.7 states:

> A destructor can be declared virtual (10.3) or pure virtual (10.4); if
>   any objects of that class or any derived class are created in the
>   program, the destructor shall be defined. If a class has a base class
>   with a virtual destructor, its destructor (whether user- or
>   implicitly- declared) is virtual.

My way of disabling the warning is to add the following lines to the header:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) && (_MSC_VER <= 1600)
#  pragma warning(disable:4505)
#endif
```

If you want to disable the warnings more locally then `#pragma warning( push )` and `#pragma warning( pop )` might be of help. See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Since the code seems to get called you can ignore the warnings in my opinion.

Comment: I'd be interested to know where this bug was reported so I can cite it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try defining the destructors in a non-inline manner?  Perhaps the warning is related to that.

Such as [this code](http://codepad.org/AxK3FCrf).

Comment: I tried the code in your link; it gets the same warning even though, as before, it functions correctly when run.

Answer (score 0):

The code should not compile. Pure virtual functions cannot be defined inside the class definition. Move the definition outside of the classes:

```
struct IAlpha {
  virtual ~IAlpha() = 0;
};
inline IAlpha::~IAlpha() {}
// similarly for the rest.
```

Besides that, the code is correct and should compile.

Comment: Interesting; I didn't know that you couldn't combining the pure virtual specifier and the method body.  Unfortunately, I tried it this way as well and the warning still shows up (see answer from jeffmagill).

Answer (score 0):

You can't define the virtual function to inline.

Because the inline is in compile.
The virtual is in runtime.